# How to compile graphicsmagick with webp support

Tags: compiling, webp

So I'm trying to compile graphicsmagick with webp support...

I've run

```
yum install libwebp libwebp-dev
```

I've added the `libwebp.a` library from [google](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/).

And I add the `--with-webp` flag to the `./configure` line.

I've managed to take it from:

```
checking for WEBP support ... 
checking webp/decode.h usability... no
checking webp/decode.h presence... no
checking for webp/decode.h... no
checking webp/encode.h usability... no
checking webp/encode.h presence... no
checking for webp/encode.h... no
checking for WebPDecodeRGB in -lwebp... no
checking for WebPMuxSetImage in -lwebpmux... no
checking if WEBP package is complete... no -- some components failed test
```

To

```
checking for WEBP support ... 
checking webp/decode.h usability... no
checking webp/decode.h presence... no
checking for webp/decode.h... no
checking webp/encode.h usability... no
checking webp/encode.h presence... no
checking for webp/encode.h... no
checking for WebPDecodeRGB in -lwebp... yes
checking for WebPMuxSetImage in -lwebpmux... no
checking if WEBP package is complete... no -- some components failed test
```

So only the `checking for WebPDecodeRGB in -lwebp` has changed.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to run

```
yum install libwebp libwebp-dev libwebp-tools libwebp-devel
```